# Rails 4 - cannot change CSS without rake assets:precompile which breaks Javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

If I make a change to application.css.scss, no changes are reflected unless I do `rake assets:precompile`.  However, when I run that, none of the JavaScript in my application works.  At that point, I have no way of getting the JavaScript to work unless I re-clone the application from GitHub (which wipes out my CSS changes of course).  This is all on a local development environment.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Not enough information in your question for us to answer. Are you running in development? Have you tried `rake assets:clubber`? You shouldn't need to precompile your assets unless you're going into production. If you've already precompiled you might need to clean them up using clubber.

Comment: I did say that is in in a "local development environment".  It seems as though running `rake assets:clobber` rather than `rake assets:clubber` did the trick.  If you submit as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I only read the `local environment`. You can still run `production` in a local environment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running in development environment should not use precompiled assets unless you've previously precompiled them.

Clean them up with `rake assets:clobber` and it should pick up your assets as opposed to the precompiled ones.